# autoresponder mail error 503

Tags: php, email, smtp

i have installed an autoresponder mail in my project and it worked well until a week ago... now i got this error:

Could not send autoresponse e-mail. (-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error: 503-Unexisting, forged or unallowed sender address (mail@mail.com) 503-used with authenticated connection (mail@mail.com) 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA)

can anybody can explain to me what kind of error is this? or what can i do in order to resolve? cause i don't know almost nothing about mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one pop3 account and use it in your autoresponder as 'from email'. Do not use alias email address.